# What is the largest array (of integers) capacity in Swift?

Tags: arrays, int, max, swift4, capacity

I tried to create an array of integers as large as possible.

Array initializer below accepts integer for count, so I thought I could use the Int.max there.

```
let maxCapacity = Int.max
var result = Array<Int>(repeating: -1, count: maxCapacity)
```

But I got the following error.
[image]
What is the maximum capacity I can use to create an array?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what `Int.max` is, and how that compares to how much memory your machine has?

Comment: @ScottHunter when I print Int.max I see this number: 9223372036854775807 that array would be very large indeed :]

Comment: So the more relevant question is: how big an array do you actually need?